# Insert SVG using Catalyst Framework

Tags: perl, svg, catalyst

I would like to add an SVG bar chart into my web application.
I have to use Catalyst Framework and Template::Toolkit view.
While searching cpan, I have found [this module](http://search.cpan.org/~terencemo/Catalyst-View-SVG-TT-Graph-0.0225/lib/Catalyst/View/SVG/TT/Graph.pm).

I followed the example instructions in the above web-page in order to create a simple graph.
Unfortunately, no chart is rendered in my application.

Firstly I created the view class

`./script/myapp_create.pl view Chart SVG::TT::Graph`

and added this code inside it

```
package myapp::View::Chart;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use SVG::TT::Graph::BarHorizontal;

 my @fields = qw(Jan Feb Mar);
  my @data_sales_02 = qw(12 45 21);

  my $graph = SVG::TT::Graph::BarHorizontal->new({
    'height' => '500',
    'width' => '300',
    'fields' => \@fields,
  });

  $graph->add_data({
    'data' => \@data_sales_02,
    'title' => 'Sales 2002',
  });

  print "Content-type: image/svg+xml\n\n";
  print $graph->burn();
```

Then I set the chart preferences in my config

```
<View::Chart>
    format         png
    <chart_conf>
        style_sheet         /home/john/myapp/root/static/css/style2.css
        show_graph_title    1
    </chart_conf>
</View::Chart>
```

Finally I created the below subroutine in my controller

```
sub getchart :Local :Args(0){

my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
$c->stash->{chart_title} = 'Sales data'; # optional

$c->stash->{chart_type} = 'BarHorizontal'; # or Pie/Line/BarHorizontal

$c->stash->{chart_conf} = {
    height  => 400,
    width   => 600
    };

$c->stash->{chart_fields} = [ qw(Jan Feb March) ];
$c->stash->{chart_data} = [ 12, 45, 21];    
$c->forward($c->view('Chart'));
}
```

Obviously I am missing something fundamental but I am inexperienced with Catalyst. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the contents of `myapp::View::Chart` from? That's not what the `myapp_create.pl` script wrote for you, it's not a View class, and it's not even a class. And you never use `print` in Catalyst.

Comment: You are right, I have added the code found from [this page](https://metacpan.org/pod/SVG::TT::Graph::BarHorizontal#new) into the file created by myapp_create.pl. Thanks for helping. Any guidance would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your are printing your graph results to *STDOUT*. Perhaps this is ending up in your server logs or somewhere else, but if you want Catalyst to send something to a client you have to set the body of your server response. The message body is accessible through the Catalyst [context](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst%3a%3aManual%3a%3aIntro#Context).

There is already some [sample code](http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2012/19) on how to print graphs using a [Catalyst::View](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst%3a%3aView) in the fabulous Catalyst Advent Calendar. At the end of the view's *process* subroutine you can see how to set the response body.

You could use this sample code and just replace the graph generator with some SVG creation module of your choice.